# How can I have different filtered views for a data stream in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to setting up different views for a Google Analytics 4 property  in order to filter data by different necessity and maintaining one view for all data with no filters. Similarly to what is available in Google Analytics Universal.

How can I do that in Google Analytics 4?  Do I need to create different streams for this purpose? and applying filters accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

In GA4 there aren't Views. You have to create reports (in GA or BigQuery) based on what you want to see on the data as you collected it.

Comment: Can you provide any specific instruction for this?